# Application is running but I cannot see anything on the screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am working on react native application. I have two components `Home` and `About`. I imported them into `App.js`. I am using `createBottomTabNavigator`. Below is my `App.js` file.

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */

import React from 'react';
import type {Node} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

import HomeScreen from './components/HomeScreen';
import AboutScreen from './components/AboutScreen';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const App: () => Node = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer initialRouteName="Home">
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="About" component={AboutScreen} />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here are my components.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', color: 'red' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

About

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default function AboutScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>About Screen</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

After this application is running but I cannot see anything on the screen. Here is the output.

[image]

Now what am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Following @nithinpp answer I get this error now.

```
Error: Requiring unknown module "undefined". If you are sure the module exists, try restarting Metro. You may also want to run `yarn` or `npm install`.
MaybeScreen@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mynio&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:123520:24
RCTView
View
MaybeScreenContainer@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mynio&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:123489:23
RNCSafeAreaProvider
SafeAreaProvider@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mynio&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:121702:24
SafeAreaProviderCompat@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mynio&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:123278:24
BottomTabView@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mynio&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:111962:30
BottomTabNavigator@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mynio&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:111824:32
EnsureSingleNavigator@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mynio&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:116000:24
BaseNavigationContainer@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mynio&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:115512:28
ThemeProvider@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mynio&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:121023:21
NavigationContainerInner@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mynio&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:120883:26
App
RCTView
View
RCTView
View
AppContainer@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mynio&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:75604:36
mynio(RootComponent)@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mynio&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:82460:28
 ERROR  Error: Requiring unknown module "undefined". If you are sure the module exists, try restarting Metro. You may also want to run `yarn` or `npm install`.
MaybeScreen@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mynio&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:123520:24
RCTView
View
MaybeScreenContainer@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mynio&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:123489:23
RNCSafeAreaProvider
SafeAreaProvider@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mynio&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:121702:24
SafeAreaProviderCompat@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mynio&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:123278:24
BottomTabView@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mynio&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:111962:30
BottomTabNavigator@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mynio&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:111824:32
EnsureSingleNavigator@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mynio&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:116000:24
BaseNavigationContainer@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mynio&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:115512:28
ThemeProvider@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mynio&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:121023:21
NavigationContainerInner@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mynio&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:120883:26
App
RCTView
View
RCTView
View
AppContainer@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mynio&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:75604:36
mynio(RootComponent)@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.mynio&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:82460:28
 ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[6], "@react-navigation/elements").ResourceSavingView')

This error is located at:
    in MaybeScreen (at BottomTabView.tsx:122)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at ScreenFallback.tsx:31)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (at BottomTabView.tsx:93)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:76)
    in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:46)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at BottomTabView.tsx:92)
    in BottomTabView (at createBottomTabNavigator.tsx:112)
    in Unknown (at createBottomTabNavigator.tsx:111)
    in BottomTabNavigator (at App.js:44)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:429)
    in BaseNavigationContainer (at NavigationContainer.tsx:132)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:131)
    in NavigationContainerInner (at App.js:43)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:48)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:133)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:41)
    in mynio(RootComponent) (at renderApplication.js:57)
 ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[6], "@react-navigation/elements").ResourceSavingView')

This error is located at:
    in MaybeScreen (at BottomTabView.tsx:122)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at ScreenFallback.tsx:31)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (at BottomTabView.tsx:93)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:76)
    in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:46)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at BottomTabView.tsx:92)
    in BottomTabView (at createBottomTabNavigator.tsx:112)
    in Unknown (at createBottomTabNavigator.tsx:111)
    in BottomTabNavigator (at App.js:44)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:429)
    in BaseNavigationContainer (at NavigationContainer.tsx:132)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:131)
    in NavigationContainerInner (at App.js:43)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:48)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:133)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:41)
    in mynio(RootComponent) (at renderApplication.js:57)
```

Comment: Seems you have added another screen `MaybeScreen` and importing library `@react-navigation/elements`?

Comment: No I am not. I do not have another screen. Atleast I do not see it anywhere neither I created it.

Comment: can you try restarting your bundler and try again?. `yarn start --reset-cache`

Comment: Just did it and same error.

Comment: I think the error is somewhere here `in BottomTabView (at createBottomTabNavigator.tsx:112)
    in Unknown (at createBottomTabNavigator.tsx:111)`

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to reproduce that error. Can you refer the snack in my answer and confirm the code is the same?

Comment: and what versions of `@react-navigation/native` and `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs` are you using?

Comment: Yes the code is the same. No difference. Here are the versions I am using `"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",`

Comment: I am also not using expo or expo cli. I used `react-native init projectname` to generate the project.

Comment: I still cant reproduce that error. Please check https://github.com/nithinpp69/navigation-test.git

Comment: Your version works fine on my computer too. I deleted my project and created another from scratch using `react-native init project` command and it is also working.

Comment: Seems the issue is something else. Anyway your OP issue was that you missed that `Tab.Navigator`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to wrap your `Tab.Screen` inside a `Tab.Navigator`. This will register those screens to the variable created with `createBottomTabNavigator();`

Simply change your `App.js` to return

```js
const App: () => Node = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="About" component={AboutScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

https://snack.expo.dev/@nithinpp69/amused-hummus

Comment: I did what you mentioned but now I am getting another error. I posted that error in my post. Could you have a look at it?